# Creating React components that *may* be used in Redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux

Imagine you have a relatively simple component you create as part of a component library (simplified for brevity):

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        getAsyncData().then((response) => {
            const {a} = response.data;
            this.setState({a});
            this.props.notify({a});
        });    
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h1>{this.state.a}</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

**The component is required** to allow dropping it into an application (think Google Maps for relatively similar approach) and have it *just work*. It can, however, share its `data` from `response` with the rest of the application, via some sort of callback (see `this.props.notify` above) it may receive via its `props`. **This is an actual requirement and not a architectural choice**.

Since this is a part of a library - you don't know what kind of application it is going to get used in *at all times*, but you do know that in *many many cases* it is going to get used in a **Redux** application.

For Redux application the above self-contained approach is not necessarily the best - as the retrieved `data` in `response` is better kept in **application state** in Redux **store**, where it can be consumed by other parts of application.

Even more so - the `ExampleComponent` itself is better off being "passive" and not having `state` at all, rather using `mapStateToProps` to have Redux infrastructure inject the state update into it via `props`.

> The idea is that when `ExampleComponent` is *in* Redux application - its `setState` call and reference to `this.state` in its `render` method are somehow abstracted and "re-routed" to `props` via Redux?

One way would be to make `ExampleComponent` to use `dispatch` that by default calls `setState` and can be overridden by injected Redux `dispatch` - basically take this to Redux:

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.dispatch = this.props.dispatch || this.dispatch;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        getAsyncData().then((response) => {
            this.dispatch({type: 'SOME_ACTION', data: response.data});
        });    
    }

    dispatch(action) {
        swtich (action.type) {
        case 'SOME_ACTION':
            const {a} = action.data;
            this.setState({a});
        case 'ANOTHER_ACTION': ...                
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h1>{this.state.a}</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

The above example works very well, save for:

1. `this.state.a` and its kin being sprinkled around the code whereas in Redux **it should be `this.props.state`**
2. having to do `this.dispatch = this.props.dispatch || this.dispatch;` in every component

> I would like to avoid the obvious `BaseComponent` solutions that would abstract `setState` into some kind of hybrid... as this would take the code, with time, further away from "canonical" React.

**Do you see an elegant way where the two approaches can be combined, with Redux superseding the inherent one?**

Comment: Whoa. What's your actual question? Could you maybe do some serious trimming down of your question to make it more succinct?

Comment: No, this is a trimmed down as possible, without loosing context. And the actual question is stated at the bottom of the Q in bold.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a fundamental mistake in thinking that a React component with Redux is different from a React component without Redux.

In fact, a React component is just a React component.

This is all your component needs to look like:

```
function ExampleComponent({ a }) {
  return (
    <h1>{a}</h1>
  );
}
```

Simple, clean, readable, testable.

There's no obvious reason why your asynchronous data fetch should be buried inside the component's `componentDidMount()` method. It can be triggered anywhere else in the application. And it should be.

Comment: While I understand the desire to make most components into pure UI functions, that is not always the case. **There is no mistake here, and I most certainly don't confuse React with Redux or make an unnecessary distinction.** There is a **clear requirement** that the component is to be self-contained, where you can embed it in ANY application - which means that it should come with its own data retrieval mechanism. Ignoring that requirement in order to make my world all rosy is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: A requirement that a view layer component must have its own data retrieval mechanism is a terrible requirement. They are two separate concerns.

Comment: 1. That's not a view layer. That is something you would consider calling a widget, if you will. It may even get used in an Angular application, under some circumstances. 2. Welcome to enterprise. 3. If it makes it easier, you can consider this a thought experiment. **There are React components out there that retrieve data.** This much is undeniable. You may write one for a simple React app that doesn't use Flux/Redux, but **still want to be able to use it properly** in Redux app.

Comment: Sure there are React components that retrieve data. But (when done properly) it is only for their own internal purposes; for data the rest of the program has no need to access. A good example would be a select list that populates its options via AJAX. The application doesn't care about the whole list, just the choice(s). But you don't use components to store application state. That completely violates the React/Flux concept of one-way data flow. Data flows down to the view layer, not up from it. (Yes, React is the view layer. Another fundamental concept.)

Comment: You continue to ignore the very clear statement where Flux or Redux are not a given, so one-way data flow is not something you can rely upon or assume there is. But sure, let's change requirements so we can more easily fit our solutions into a specific bracket. Also, way to be condescending.